# How to fix duplicate value found in v-for?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have a Vue (1.x) based shopping basket system working in conjunction with a Laravel backend using Moltin-Cart. The basket is populated, retrieved and updated using API calls to the backend.

I can add items to the basket without an issue:

```
addToBasket: function(){
                var that = this;
                var item = this.book;
                this.$http.post('/api/buy/addToBasket', item);
                this.basketAddSuccess = true;
                setTimeout(function(){ that.basketAddSuccess = false; }, 4000);
            }
```

which hits the backend:

```
public function addToBasket(Request $request)
    {
        // grab book information
        $book = Book::find($request->id);

        // extract price from the database to ensure it's correct
        $row = $book->price;

        // create an item
        $item = array(
                'id' => $book->id,
                'name' => $book->title,
                'price' => $row,
                'quantity' => $request->qty
            );

        // Make the insertion...
        $this->cart->insert($item);
    }
```

When I hit my fetchBasket API function I get this as expected:

```
{
  027c91341fd5cf4d2579b49c4b6a90da: {
   id: 1,
   name: "Book Title",
   price: 40,
   quantity: "1"
  }
}
```

The long random string is the cart id.

The problem comes when I try to list the basket contents using a simple v-for:

```
<tr v-for="item in basketItems">
```

But this throws lots of errors:

```
[Vue warn]: Duplicate value found in v-for="item in basketItems": "0". Use track-by="$index" if you are expecting duplicate values.
```

One error for each character in the JSON string, in fact.

So Googling around I find  `track-by` and try to implement it first with item.id:

```
<tr v-for="item in basketItems" track-by="item.id">
```

This throws

```
VM4389:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

then with $index:

```
<tr v-for="item in basketItems" track-by="$index">
```

This doesn't throw an error, but it instead creates an empty basket item entry in the basket view for each character in the JSON string.

Any ideas as to how to fix it?

EDIT:

```
public function fetchBasket()
    {
        return ($this->cart->contents(true));
    }
```

Comment: Can you show **fetchBasket API** code?

Comment: your response is an object and you are treating it like an array

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham added. The 'true' flag sets the contents to return as an array (which for some reason actually is an object).

Answer (score 0):

The `track-by` in `v-for` already considers you are referencing a property of the iterated variable (in your case, `item`), so no need for `track-by="item.id"`, just do:

```html
<tr v-for="item in basketItems" track-by="id">
```

If you see nothing after this, I suggest you try simply printing the `name`:

```html
<table>
  <tr v-for="item in basketItems" track-by="id">
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Because, remember, the browsers **won't render** `<tr>`s that are not under a `<table>`.

Comment: yes, unfortunately it doesn't work. It still throws an error for each character in the JSON string. The <tr> is in a <table>, I just didn't copy and paste the whole table code for brevity.